# Getting an error with my query

Tags: php, mysql

What is wrong with this line of code?

```
$query= "SELECT status FROM follow WHERE user_id1= $COOKIE['user_id'] AND user_id2=  
$user_id";
```

I keep getting the error message:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Comment: Try `echo $query`. It might give a hint as to what the problem is.

Comment: Have you heard of little Bobby Tables? http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: "What is wrong with this line of code?"? Oh, so very, very much.

Answer (score 4):

Your solution is vulnerable to SQL injection; what happens if my cookie's userid is `1; drop table follow; --`? Say goodbye to your follow table.

You need to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` (edit: and put quotes around the interpolated variable) at the very least, see [this page](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php) for details. But really you want [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Any reason they need to use mysql_real_escape_string()?

Comment: Because inserting raw user-supplied data into a SQL query is wrong.

Comment: It's almost as if mysql_real_escape_string was designed to escape strings before passing them to MySQL!

Comment: Great. Unfortunately, I see no strings inserted in this query. Do you see any?

Comment: What if a user sets their user_id cookie?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use quoted array keys inside a string.  You have to use the `{...}` syntax, or drop the quotes (which would issue a warning *outside* a string, but you know, PHP.)

Everyone insisting you use `mysql_real_escape_string` is correct, and everyone insisting you use PDO with prepared statements is far more correct.

Comment: Everyone insisting you use mysql_real_escape_string is IN-friggin-correct and have no clue.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
$query= "SELECT status FROM follow WHERE user_id1 = {$_COOKIE['user_id']}
AND user_id2 = {$user_id}";
```

> What is wrong with this line of code?

Basically, you have an array `$COOKIE`, which I believe was intended to be `$_COOKIE` that you are accessing, but since it is encapsulated in a string, you need to assist PHP's parser to indicate that yes, it actually is a variable (array) and not part of the string. To do that, you should encapsulate your variables around `{$like_this}` when using them inside "strings";

Answer (score -4):

single quotes delimiting an array key causing this error
either omit these quotes inside of the string or use curly braces.

you have to also ensure that your values that go into query have proper format

```
$user_id1 = (int)$COOKIE['user_id'];
$user_id2 = (int)$user_id;
$query="SELECT status FROM follow WHERE user_id1=$user_id1  AND user_id2=$user_id2";
```

Comment: What if the userids aren't ints?

Comment: *Sigh* This is more correct than `mysql_real_escape_string`, at least.